# First line of some HTTP Responses turned into "undefined undefined undefined"

Tags: php, sockets, http, firefox, response

Writing a socket server with PHP 7.2. Randomly, the first line of some HTTP Responses from the server became `undefined undefined undefined` according to the Network tab in Firefox 60. So I tried to log down all the responses sent by the socket server, as follows:

```
file_put_contents("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Logs\\".strlen($response).".txt", $response);
socket_write($client, $response, strlen($response));
```

However, when looking at the logs, the same HTTP Responses that started with `undefined undefined undefined` in Firefox are all okay. Those logs all started with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` just like how they are supposed to be.

This problem is really stopping my process because it made doing everything with the socket server so unreliable. But I could not find the source of the problem after debugging the PHP code for a few hours. Any tips?

**Bonus Information:** For some reason, the same socket server does not work in Chrome, which displays an error message with the error code being `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`. It only works in Firefox. I also tried using CURL to connect to the same socket server, but it says `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was aborted`.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by myself! For some reason, adding `socket_set_block($socket);` on the line immediately after `socket_listen($socket);` solves the problem.